# Is it possible to send multiple data in one view on Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to pass several data to one view. I can send the products to it but I would like to send the categories as well. I want to send them separately and not with a join. I have been advised to put it after the "then" but I don't know how to do it.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  models.produit.findAll(
    {
      include: 
      [
        {
          model: models.image, as: "images" 
        },
        {
          model: models.promotionproduit, as: "promotionproduits",
          include:[{model: models.promotion, as: "Promotion"}]
        }
      ]})
      .then(data => {
        res.render('home', {
          data: data
        });
      
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: You can make numerous requests for data before you render. Do the categories need to be merged with products, or vice versa? Not really enough known regarding the display relationships you are looking for

Comment: What are the categories and how do you access them?

Comment: What I want to do is to get my products with data and make another query that would return the categories with data2 for example and there in my view I could do as follows:
<% data.forEach(function(product) { %>...
<% data.forEach(function(category) { %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use async/await to build up your data then pass it to the view.

```js
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {

  // define your data var
  const data = {
    errors: {}
    produits: [],
    categories: []
  }

  // get produits
  try {
    data.produits = await models.produit.findAll({
      include: [{
          model: models.image,
          as: "images"
        },
        {
          model: models.promotionproduit,
          as: "promotionproduits",
          include: [{
            model: models.promotion,
            as: "Promotion"
          }]
        }
      ]
    })
  } catch {
    data.errors.produits = 'Échec du chargement des produits.'
  }

  // get categories
  try {
    // as above, do your model...
  } catch {
    data.errors.categories = 'Échec du chargement des catégories.'
  }

  res.render('home', {
    data
  });
});
```

Comment: I am new to this language so thanks for your answer, you help me a lot.

Comment: np, in your view, just access via `data.categories` which would be an array you can forEach over, if you check for data.errors.categories you can show the error etc. If you want it up one level, ie. `categories.forEach` just do `res.render('home', data);`, good luck

Comment: Perfect for tips